# Xamarin and CSS

Tags: css, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie with cross platform mobile development and tools like Xamarin so please excuse me if this question appears to be stupid.

My app would target Android, iOS, Windows Phone. I would want to know if i can add CSS in the UI layer (Xamarin.forms app or separately in Xamarin.Android/Ios/Windows ).?. So that i can make attractive UI for the apps.

Is it possible to add CSS in Xamarin.forms/Xamarin.Android apps UI ?

If yes:

1. Then how can it be done?
2. Please If you can provide some resource link it would be very helpful.

If no:

1. How Can I make attractive UI with the built-in resources? (need some tips)
2. Please If you can provide some resource link it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In xamarin there isn't something like CSS. However there is concept of [Resource Dictionary](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/), through which you can make a separate file that defines the styles for controls and views in a central location. Have a look to [this](http://xamarinhelp.com/styling-uiux-day-11/).

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Forms 3.0, CSS is introduced:

Usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StyleSheet Source="/Assets/styles.css" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Announcement: https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-0-released

Need a training video? https://university.xamarin.com/lightninglectures/xamarin-forms-30-css